# numerical integration methods question python

Tags: python, numerical-methods

I am trying to integrate the following formula:

[image]

Below is my attempt to perform this integration using a homemade scheme for `f(a) = sin(a)`.

```
def func(x):
    return math.sin(x)

def integration (f, n, r, a, dtheta ):

    summation = 0
    theta = 0
    while theta <= 2*np.pi:

        f_arg = a + r*np.exp(1j*theta)
        second = np.exp(-1j*theta*n)

        summation += f(f_arg) * second * dtheta
        theta += dtheta

    return math.factorial(n)*summation / (2*np.pi*r**n)

integration(func, n=1, r=1, a=0, dtheta=2*np.pi/10000)
```

The first derivative (`n=1`) of `f(a) = sin(a)` is `f'(a) = cos(a)`. When evaluated at `a = 0`, this should give `cos(0) = 1`, however, it does not. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `return math.factorial(n) / (2*np.pi*r**n)` doesn't seem to involve `f`, `theta`, `dtheta`, or anything you did in the `while` loop.

Comment: @user2357112, thank you for attention, updating question (as that was a typo), still didn't fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your problem is the `math.sin` function, which doesn't support complex arguments:

```
i = np.exp(.5j * np.pi)
math.sin(i), np.sin(i)
(6.123233995736766e-17, (9.44864380126377e-17+1.1752011936438014j))
```

It also throws a warning (but not an error...):

```
ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
```

Using `np.sin` instead fixes the problem.

In general, the implementation might be simpler to express (and easier to debug) with more use of numpy, like

```
def integration(func, a, n, r, n_steps):
    z = r * np.exp(2j * np.pi * np.arange(0, 1, 1. / n_steps))
    return math.factorial(n) * np.mean(func(a + z) / z**n)

np.allclose(1., integration(np.sin, a=0., n=1, r=1., n_steps=100))

True
```

Comment: [Replacing `math.sin` with `np.sin` isn't enough to produce a result of 1 when I try it.](https://ideone.com/KuW49P)

Comment: @user2357112 in the original example there is also n=2 used instead of n=1 in the function call. If you change this it is OK. Have edited question.