# Derivatives in python

Tags: python, math, derivative

I am trying to find the coefficients of a finite series, $f(x) = \sum_n a_nx^n$. To get the $m$th coefficient, we can take the $m$th [derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2180243/extracting-coefficients-from-a-generating-function-g-x) evaluated at zero. Therefore, the $m$th coefficient is

```
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i } \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}} dz
$$
```

I believe this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53269229/numerical-integration-methods-question-python/53269537#53269537) takes the derivative of a function using the above contour integral.

```
import math
import numpy

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def F(x):
    mean=10
    return math.exp(mean*(x.real-1))

def p(n):
    mean=10
    return (math.pow(mean, n) * math.exp(-mean)) / math.factorial(n)

def integration(func, a, n, r, n_steps):
    z = r * numpy.exp(2j * numpy.pi * numpy.arange(0, 1, 1. / n_steps))
    return math.factorial(n) * numpy.mean(func(a + z) / z**n)

ns = list(range(20))
f2 = numpy.vectorize(F)

plt.plot(ns,[p(n) for n in ns], label='Actual')
plt.plot(ns,[integration(f2, a=0., n=n, r=1., n_steps=100).real/math.factorial(n) for n in ns], label='Numerical derivative')

plt.legend()
```

[image]

However, it is clear that the numerical derivative is completely off the actual values of the coefficients of the series. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" <- You're attempting to apply Cauchy's integral theorem (which requires a holomorphic function) to a function `F` that isn't holomorphic.

Comment: Suggested minimal fix: import [`cmath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html), and replace the `return` statement in `F` with `return cmath.exp(mean*(x-1))` (in other words, replace `x.real` with `x` and `math.exp` with `cmath.exp`). For me, this gives two graphs that line up perfectly.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thank you for your help. Write it as an answer and I will accept it. Out of interest, why does it work at all if F isn't holomorphic?

Comment: "why does it work at all if F isn't holomorphic?" I don't think it does - in your definition of `F`, you take the real part of `x` - that's the bit that makes `F` non-holomorphic. By replacing `x.real` with `x`, `F` becomes holomorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulas in the [Mathematics Stack Exchange answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2180243/117283) that you're using to derive the coefficients of the power series expansion of `F` are based on complex analysis - coming for example from Cauchy's residue theorem (though other derivations are possible). One of the assumptions necessary to make those formulas work is that you have a holomorphic (i.e., complex differentiable) function.

Your definition of `F` gives a function that's not holomorphic. (For one thing, it always gives a real result for any complex input, which isn't possible for a non-constant holomorphic function.) But it's easily fixed to be holomorphic, while continuing to return the same result for real inputs.

Here's a fixed version of `F`, which replaces `x.real` with `x`. Since the input to `exp` is now complex, it's also necessary to use `cmath.exp` instead of `math.exp` to avoid a `TypeError`:

```
import cmath

def F(x):
    mean=10
    return cmath.exp(mean*(x-1))
```

After that fix for `F`, if I run your code I get rather surprisingly accurate results. Here's the graph that I get. (I had to print out the values to double check that that graph really did show two lines on top of one another.)

[image]